# How do I search for Safari Extensions?

Tags: search, safari-extensions

I noticed that Safari has an [Extensions Gallery](https://extensions.apple.com/) page. I'm wondering how I would search all the extensions to find the one I want.

Does that page list all of the extensions available, meaning I should use Edit > Find...? Or are there many more which aren't listed on the page?

Comment: This is nuts that this isn't super easy. What are the on??

Answer (score 4):

There are many extensions not listed on Apple's page. However, if they're not on the main page, they're not on Apple's site at all. Your `cmd-f` solutions is the best option if you want to search just the extensions that Apple has listed.

If you want to broaden your search to more of the extensions available, turn to third-party sites: http://safariextensions.org/, http://safariextensions.tumblr.com/, and http://www.pimpmysafari.com/category/extensions are all good, more-comprehensive lists.

Comment: … Which is a shame and a fatal miss by Apple, to not understand that they need to establish proper extension search as well as creating something at least remotely reminiscent of e.g. Chrome's and Firefox' 'web store' solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Missing Safari Extensions Gallery [Search Engine is hosted at hakore.com](http://hakore.com/safariextensions/) now. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be operative enough to give any search results any longer. Meanwhile Apple has added a rudimentary search to [the extension gallery page](https://safari-extensions.apple.com) that at least works and gives some results. This only works for extensions listed by Apple. Google is the only solution I know of at the moment for [finding extensions](https://www.google.se/#q=Safari+extensions) hosted elsewhere.